# How to call a generator (async) function on an interval basis

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, setinterval, adonis.js

I am building an app that must poll remote devices (generator fn `sendRequests()`) every 2 seconds.

What's the right way to call the generator fn using setInterval, which isn't a generator and doesn't yield

```
function * sendRequests() {
  // multiple remote async requests are sent
}

var timer = setInterval(() => {
  // yield sendRequests()
}, 2000)
```

Comment: Why is that a generator function? Shouldn't it be an `async function` at most? Have you forgotten to wrap it in `co.wrap` (or whatever async runner library you are using)?

Comment: I'll update the question for clarity but the function is a generator. Its on the AdonisJS platform that uses generators in place of promises and callbacks for async operations and is  not yet prepped for ES7 async fns. In this case, the async action is a remote MODBUS/TCP request.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with yielding from the `setInterval` callback is that `yield` can only yield to the generator `function*` that immediately contains it. Therefore, you can't `yield` from a callback.

What you can do from a callback is resolve a Promise, which your generator function can `yield`:

```js
async function* pollGen() {
  yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setInterval(() => resolve(...), 2000);
  });
```

The problem with that is a [Promise can only be settled once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449469/promise-is-only-firing-once/33449515#33449515). Therefore, calling `resolve` every 2000ms won't do anything beyond the first call.

What you can do instead is call `setTimeout` repeatedly, in a while loop:

```js
async function* pollGen() {
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10)
    yield new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(i++), 200);
    });
}

(async function main() {
  // for-await-of syntax
  for await (const result of pollGen())
    console.log(result);
}());
```

The new [`for-await-of`](http://2ality.com/2017/12/for-await-of-sync-iterables.html) syntax has been available since Node v9.2, and can be used in Node v10 or later without any flags.

Comment: This works but your while loop is basically blocking the execution as long as the promise is not resolved which kinda defeat the purpose of your `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 0):

Since AdonisJS uses co() under the hood, I used @Bergi suggestion of wrapping in co()

```
function * sendRequests() {
  // multiple remote async requests are sent
}

var timer = setInterval(() => {
  co(function * () {
    yield sendRequests()
  })
}, 2000)
```